# Unity3D: Collisions, Getting the Normal of the Collision Surface (Not the Angle of Impact)

Tags: collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my first Unity project right now (a bit of a self prescribed crash-course) and I've run into a slight issue.

I'm trying deflect one object off of another one (via collision).  For now, the deflection should be at a perfectly mirrored angle.  No problem! I think to myself, I see this super handy `contact.normal` property; seems pretty straight forward (I'm working in a 2D plane, so it really should be have been smooth sailing from there).

A few frustratingly failed attempts, and several thousand `drawRay` commands later, I realize that the normal is NOT a normal to the face of impact, but is a normal OF the impact (ie, mirrors the angle of impact).

This is actually useful information, but to be useful, I need a face-normal to reflect the angle of impact over.

The moving object is using `this.rigidbody.velocity =` so I can't rely on built in physics; I'm also being a total stickler for how this bounce looks, so I'd really love to maintain full control over it.

Relevant code below:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(collision : Collision)
{
    var contactCount : int = 0;
    var normalAve : Vector3 = Vector3(0,0,0);
    var velocityAve : Vector3 = Vector3.zero;

    for (var contact : ContactPoint in collision.contacts)
    {
        contactCount++;
        normalAve += contact.normal;

        velocityAve += collision.relativeVelocity;
        Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.green, 2, false);
    }

    normalAve /= contactCount;
    velocityAve /= contactCount;

    var damage = Vector3.Dot(normalAve, velocityAve) * collision.rigidbody.mass;



    life -= damage;

    if(life <= 0)
    {
        // Stackoverflow people can ignore this, bounces
        // don't happen when you're dead
        this.rigidbody.useGravity = this.GetComponent(ship_small_physics).stage.GetComponent(stage_params).grav_on_hit;

        this.GetComponent(ship_small_physics).impact();
    }else{
        // Stackoverflow people! Right here!
        Debug.Log("survived! with " + life + " life");
        this.GetComponent(ship_small_physics).small_impact(normalAve, velocityAve);
    }
}
```

Then, in `.small_impact`

```
function small_impact(n : Vector3, v : Vector3)
{
    var h_angle : Vector3 = Vector3(n.x, 0, n.z);
    Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, n, Color.blue, 2, false);
    Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, h_angle, Color.red, 2, false);
}
```

Just to clarify:  The game IS in some sorts of 3D, but for various reasons in this case I only care about the collision normals in the `x-z` plane (another reason why the plane old physics engine won't do).  That's why I make a new vector `h_angle` that's essentially the projection of the collision-normal onto the `x-z` plane.

Comment: Do I understand you right that the normal is just a vector perpendicular to the (relative) object velocity starting from contact point? And because there is an infinite number of orthonormal vectors (in 3D) you cannot rely on that you get the same result for the same collision a second time. Sounds strange but anyway an interesting problem :-)

Comment: All except the perpendicular to the velocity bit; it's parallel.  The weird thing is, when I set up a test case with simple moving objects, the normal returned from collisions is the surface normal, not the impact normal.  Something's fishy.

Comment: Maybe the colliders are adjusted wrong because of 2D projection.

Comment: I thought that, too.  So I drew both the origInal vector and the projected one to check.  They line up.  I also draw each contacts normal (before the averaging) and they're still angled.  Bit of a head scratcher that...